# What is the relationship between ui and this in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, ownership-semantics

If you create a Qt widget application with class name `MainWindow`, Qt Creator will give you this template header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and this template source:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

What is `ui`? What is its relationship to `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The qt program `uic` compiles the `.ui` file to a `.h` file. It makes a class that holds pointers to all the widgets defined in the form, and a member function `setupUi` which constructs all those widgets, setting the properties specified in the form, with the top-level widget being a direct child of the passed in widget (your `MainWindow` instance in this case). It doesn't automatically show any window, other code calls the `show` member of your main window.

If you create another `Ui::MainWindow` and call it's `setupUi`, you will populate another widget with all the descendant widgets described in the form.

Comment: ```setupUi```sets the parent of the widgets to ```MainWindow```, but ```MainWindow``` doesn't ```delete``` widgets in its destructor. Who is in charge of deleting the widgets:  ```MainWindow``` or ```Ui::MainWindow```?

Comment: @Bobby [Object Trees & Ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html).

Comment: @Bobby the `QObject` base-subobject of `MainWindow`